# Use structs in aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Is it possible to support using structs in aggregate initialization without creating a constructor for each case? This is what I'm talking about:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x, y, z;
}

struct Vector2 {
    float x, y;
}


Vector2 vec2 { 1, 2 };
Vector3 vec3 { vec2, 3 };
```

Comment: No that's not possible. You need to create constructors. Well, that maybe could be automated using some template metaprogramming magic with variadic templates.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for structured bindings? have a look this link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding